# Disable Auto-Scaling of an AKS Node pool via Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have an AKS with 3 Node pools - 2 USER type and 1 SYSTEM type.
I want to create an automation via Azure runbooks that will scale the 2 USER type Node pools to zero during off-hours and then re-enable auto-scaling to the Node pools with their previous Min and Max count.

As for re-enabling the auto-scaling I found the command for that:

```
Update-AzAksNodePool -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ClusterName $AKSCluster -Name $NodePool -MinCount <Min number> -MaxCount <Max number> -EnableAutoScaling
```

But as for scaling them to zero, the following commands didn't work:

```
Update-AzAksNodePool -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ClusterName $AKSCluster -Name $NodePool -MinCount 0 -MaxCount 0
```

^ For this I get an error that MaxCount value can't be '0'

```
Update-AzAksNodePool -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ClusterName $AKSCluster -Name $NodePool -NodeCount 0
```

^ For the I don't get any error but it doesn't scale it to 0, basically does nothing.

So after this I realized that the Node pool must be in Manual scaling mode and not Autoscale for the former command to work, which means my script needs to disable the Node pool's auto-scaling or switch it to Manual scaling mode.

This is the documentation I used of the Update-AzAksNodePool command:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.aks/update-azaksnodepool?view=azps-7.3.2

The documentation does not mention any parameter to disable auto-scaling, only to enable it.
I tried running it twice with the `-EnableAutoScaling` parameter, didn't switch it.

I tried running it with `-EnableAutoScaling $false`, didn't work as well as it doesn't receive value.

There was nothing in the documentation that mentioned disabling the auto-scaling.
The only way I found doing it was via Azure CLI - which isn't available in a runbook, or via the Azure Portal - which can't be automated.

Anyone knows how to turn a Node pool's auto-scaling mode off via Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the features that are currently available, to disable an AKS node pool's auto-scaling via Powershell, I would recommend to leverage [Agent Pools - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/agent-pools/create-or-update#agentpoolmode) REST API and [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2) PowerShell cmdlets and create an Azure Automation runbook something as shown below.

```
$SubscriptionID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$ResourceGroupName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$AKSClusterName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$AgentPoolName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$URI = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionID/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/$AKSClusterName/agentPools/$AgentPoolName"+"?api-version=2022-01-01"

$Body = @{
  properties = @{
    enableAutoScaling = "false";
    mode = "System"
  }
}
$Body.properties.enableAutoScaling=$false
$JSONBody = $Body | ConvertTo-Json

$azContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
$azProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
$profileClient = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient -ArgumentList ($azProfile)
$token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($azContext.Subscription.TenantId)
$authHeader = @{
    'Content-Type'='application/json'
    'Authorization'='Bearer ' + $token.AccessToken
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Method PUT -Headers $authHeader -Body $JSONBody
$response | fl *
```

[image]

[image]

On the other hand, as we have feature to disable AKS node pool's auto-scaling via [Agent Pools - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/agent-pools/create-or-update#agentpoolmode) REST API and [az aks nodepool update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks/nodepool?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-nodepool-update-examples) CLI commands so we are supposed to have the same feature via direct Azure PowerShell cmdlet as well. So, I am reaching out to our internal team to check on this and will keep you updated as I hear more information.

**UPDATE-1:**
[image]
[image]
For more information with regards to it, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/powershell-runbook-managed-identity) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/quickstarts/enable-managed-identity) documents.

Comment: Thank you Krishna, it does seem to work though via a runbook I receive:
'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'

And when running in the CloudShell it works with no error.
I tried taking the value of the generated token from the CloudShell and inserted it as value for the runbook and that works too but probably that token is temporarily so wanted to ask if it actually is, and also if maybe there's a setting I'm missing out that denies my connection using the Automation Account's Service Principle.
(Also had to switch from mode = "System" to "User" according to my needs).

Comment: Yes, it looks like a permission issue. Ensure that the identity that you are using in the runbook has [permissions to access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current) used in the runbook.I was using managed service identity hence used the line "$azContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context" in my runbook. My system identity has owner role as shown in screenshot that's updated in the answer. Please check if that might help.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, really gave me answer about everything I needed.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Just wanted to let you know that I have provided same answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/788778/index.html) as well. Appreciate if you can accept the answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/788778/index.html) as well so it might help broader community members in that Microsoft Q&A platform as well.

Comment: Definitely, accepted there as well.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This is what worked for me:**

1. Change the scale method to Manual
2. Set the node count you want
3. Save your changes

[image: Screenshot from Azure Web-UI:]

Comment: The whole idea of this question though is to find a way to perform it via Powershell and not using the portal.

Comment: It would be nice if Azure could add the CLI syntax for the GUI actions...

Comment: Yep, sure would be...