# Is there an availability issue when using a ZRS Azure Storage Account as an AKS PVC using BlobFuse?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-storage-account

I have **manually** created a blob storage account with ZRS. I have then created a PV and PVC in AKS referencing that blob storage account using blobfuse. However, I now have this error on the AKS cluster which I don't fully understand:

[image]

Is there an availability problem here? I.e. Are the pods which mount the PVC isolated to a single zone? If so, what is the appropriate remediation?

Here is the AKS manifest for the PV:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
  name: XXXX
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: XXXX
    namespace: XXXX
  csi:
    driver: blob.csi.azure.com
    nodeStageSecretRef:
      name: XXXX
      namespace: XXXX
    volumeAttributes:
      containerName: XXXX
      protocol: fuse
      resourceGroup: XXXX
      storageAccount: XXXX
    volumeHandle: XXXX
  mountOptions:
  - --file-cache-timeout-in-seconds=120
  - -o allow_other
  - --use-adls=true
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: azureblob-fuse-premium
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

and here is the AKS manifest for the PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  name: XXXX
  namespace: XX
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: azureblob-fuse-premium
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: XXXX
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  phase: Bound
```

Comment: You can disable [disable auto-scaling of an aks node pool via azure powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71634385/disable-auto-scaling-of-an-aks-node-pool-via-azure-powershell)

Comment: Or you can follow the recommendation mentioned in the shared image [Create an AKS cluster across availability zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/availability-zones#create-an-aks-cluster-across-availability-zones)